# How to Split a table rows into fixed size chunk in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a large table 1 million+ rows with a numeric column as primary key. I was trying for an Oracle sql query to get a split of size say 500. So that I have sort of buckets that have 500 records each and give their max and min value in that bucket. 
sample data

```
pk_column column1 column2 column3
1002      abcd    1234    15-apr-20
1004      efgh    3435    14-apr-20
1007      ijkl    8855    16-apr-20
....
....
....
2002      asdf    8565    17-apr-20
2005      efgh    5894    14-apr-20
```

the desired output is something like below

```
bucket_no no_of_element min_value max_value
1         500           1002      2002
2         500           2005      3002
3         500           3003      4002
4         480           4003      4500
```

The code that I could come up with using NTILE or WIDTH_BUCKET is not able to decide the number of bucket size so that no of element is kind of fixed. As the number of elements keep changing , I am unable to find a way to calculate the bucket count dynamically and use it in the NTILE or WIDTH_BUCKET window function. Use of LEAD and LAG function in a hierarchical way was a lot confusing. Could anyone suggest how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```
SELECT
    RN   AS BUCKET_NO,
    COUNT(1) AS NO_OF_ELEMENT,
    MIN(PK_COLUMN) AS MIN_VALUE,
    MAX(PK_COLUMN) AS MAX_VALUE
FROM
    ( SELECT T.*,
            MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PK_COLUMN) - 1, 500) + 1 RN
        FROM YOUR_TABL T
    )
GROUP BY RN
```

Comment: The PK_COLUMN does not have a continuous series of numbers so using the MOD function to limit 500 records to a bucket is not working.  Though thr case should work for a continuous series

Comment: as per my testing the 500 results is the no of buckets say 500 buckets,so to get 500 elements divide no of rows by 500 and put that in the place of X in MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PK_COLUMN) - 1, X) + 1 RN