# Move a column to a new table in ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following table with lots of users:

```
USERS
-----
id
name
lastname
cv
```

and I would like to divide that table into:

```
USERS
-----
id
name
lastname

USER_CVS
--------
id
user_id
cv
```

In ORACLE my approach was to:

1. Create the USER_CVS table
2. Insert the data using a INSERT INTRO USER_CVS SELECT ... FROM USERS
3. Drop the cv column from USERS

But, there are two problems:

- in 2. the amount of data in the DB doubles and I don't have so much space.
- it takes a long time to copy the cvs

Is there another way to divide this table?

Comment: The trick I've done is to add an extra column `migrated number(1)` with value zero (false). Then, I migrate subsets of one thousand (or any other size) at a time: migrate, mark, delete, repeat. This way I don't run out of space.

Comment: Before looking at a technical solution, I'd ask why you want to do this at all?  First, every table has a certain amount of fixed and proportional overhead, so spreading x-amount of data across two tables _will_ take more space.  Second, and more importantly, how does splitting this into two table play into a properly normalized data design?

Comment: Normalizing data doesn't mean unnecessarily splitting a table into more tables and duplicating the data. If this a production level design, then you should go back to your drawing boards and think about the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the TEMP table and move the columns accordingly.

Like this:

```
--Create temp table
CREATE TABLE USERS_TEMP
AS
SELECT ID, NAME, LASTNAME FROM USERS;

--Rename ID to USER_ID in original table
ALTER TABLE USERS RENAME COLUMN ID TO USER_ID;

--Add ID column in original table
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD ID NUMBER;

--Drop name column from original table
ALTER TABLE USERS DROP COLUMN NAME; 

--Drop lastname column from original table
ALTER TABLE USERS DROP COLUMN LASTNAME;

--rename original table to USER_CVS
ALTER TABLE USERS RENAME TO USER_CVS;

--rename temp table to USERS_TEMP
ALTER TABLE USERS_TEMP RENAME TO USERS;

--use some sequence to update the ID column in USER_CVS
UPDATE USER_CVS SET ID = SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to split data into chunks in the source table and then insert the first chunk in destination table and then update the chunk to null in the source table.

After all the chunks are moved then drop the column in the source table.

The method to create chunks is given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229208/how-to-split-a-table-rows-into-fixed-size-chunk-in-oracle)